# how to display images in ViewPager from SQLite Database Table in ANdroid

Tags: android

I'm trying to show the images in View-pager.I have stored the images in SQLite table and using count function for geting count of rows of ActivityObjId. When count function returns intCount = 5 I want to display 5 place holder images shows in view pager. Please someone help me. I have this problem for last 2 to 3 days.

Here is my Activity Code

```
     public void getActivityObjectId_Count() {
            try {
                dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();


                Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select count(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where " + "activityId" + " = ?", new String[]{strDescription});
                if (cursor2 != null) {

                    cursor2.moveToFirst();

                    String strCount_ActivityObjectId = cursor2.getString(0);
                     intCount = Integer.parseInt(strCount_ActivityObjectId);

                    Log.e("intCount", "in getActivityObjectId = " + intCount);


                }

                cursor2.close();
                db.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 

class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<All_Post> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;

    ArrayList<All_Post> data = new ArrayList<All_Post>();

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<All_Post> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.txt_Descid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textDescid);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_Desc);
            holder.txtInitialLetter = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_InitialLetter);
            holder.txtRemark = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textRemark);

            holder.imgBtn_Rework = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonRework);
            holder.imgBtn_FollowUp = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonFoloowUp);
            holder.imgBtn_RateEquipMent = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonRateEquipment);
            holder.imgBtn_Camera = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonCamera);
            holder.imgBtn_Audio = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonAudio);
            holder.imgBtn_FollowInspector = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonFollowInspector);

            holder.viewPager = (ViewPager) row.findViewById(R.id.Image_ViewPagers);

            holder.viewPager.setPageMargin(-50);
            holder.viewPager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            holder.viewPager.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
            holder.viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
            holder.viewPager.setPadding(-5, 0, 0, 0);
            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext());
            holder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            holder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

        All_Post all_Post = data.get(position);


        holder.txt_Descid.setText(Integer.toString(all_Post.getID()));
        String strTextDescId = holder.txt_Descid.getText().toString().trim();
        Log.e("strTextDescId ", " = " + strTextDescId);
        getActivityId(strTextDescId);
        getActivityObjectId_Count();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(all_Post.getName());
        String strTxtTitle = holder.txtTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        Log.e("strTxtTitle ", " = " + strTxtTitle);


        holder.txtInitialLetter.setText(all_Post.getInitName());
        holder.txtRemark.setText(all_Post.getStrDesc());

        holder.imgBtn_Rework.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Button click ", "event is fire");

            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView txt_Descid;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtInitialLetter;
        TextView txtRemark;
        ViewPager viewPager;

        ImageView imgBtn_Rework;
        ImageView imgBtn_FollowUp;
        ImageView imgBtn_RateEquipMent;
        ImageView imgBtn_Camera;
        ImageView imgBtn_Audio;
        ImageView imgBtn_FollowInspector;

    }
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContent;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private List<String> testImages = new ArrayList<String>();


    private int[] GalImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder
    };


    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mContent = context;

        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContent.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.9f;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContent);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;


    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        // return PAGE_NUM;
        Log.e("intCount8888: "," = " +intCount );
        return intCount;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

        //return view.equals(obj);
        return view == ((ImageView) obj);
    }

}
```

Here is my LogCat error

```
08-07 00:48:48.176    1182-1182/? E/intCount8888:﹕ = 0
08-07 00:48:48.176    1182-1182/? E/intCount8888:﹕ = 0
08-07 00:48:48.186    1182-1182/? E/intCount8888:﹕ = 0
08-07 00:48:48.196    1182-1182/? E/strTextDescId﹕ = 1


08-07 00:48:48.316    1182-1182/? E/intCount8888:﹕ = 1
08-07 00:48:48.336    1182-1182/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-07 00:48:48.336    1182-1182/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465730)
08-07 00:48:48.446    1182-1182/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 1 Pager id: com.example.tazeen.classnkk:id/Image_ViewPagers Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:999)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
```

Comment: intCount is the variable where I'm getting count of row like ( Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select count(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where " + "activityId" + " = ?", new String[]{strDescription});) and like this = String strCount_ActivityObjectId = cursor2.getString(0);
                     intCount = Integer.parseInt(strCount_ActivityObjectId);

Comment: The error says "PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged!" are you changing the pager content after setting the  adapter?

Comment: I already calling notifyDataSetChanged like  = MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext());
                holder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I call notifyDataSetChanged(); in getCount() method getting StackOverFlowError. Why.